# Dúvida sobre Herança Visual entre Janelas em WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Sou novo em WPF e gostaria de esclarecer uma dúvida que eu acho que a maioria das pessoas têm, mas não consegue esclarecer direito, que é a herança visual de janelas.

Imaginem que todas as minhas telas de cadastro devam ter a mesma aparência e os mesmos botões (Salvar, Cancelar, etc). NO Windows Forms. por exemplo, basta criar uma janela base com os componentes citados e depois, basta fazer com que as outras janelas herdem dessa janela base e pronto!!! Caso a janela que herdar da janela base não tiver um botão específico, basta eu adicioná-lo no form normalmente.

Bom, agora vamos para o WPF. Não consigo fazer isso e não sei se existe essa possibilidade, pois o que consegui fazer é criar um User Control, mas achei muito engessado pois se eu fizer um user control de uma tela (como citei anteriormente), na janela que eu adiciono-o, não tenho como alterá-lo com novos botões para aquela janela que estiver herdando....

Alguém já passou por alguma experiência assim?

Comment: Sei que herança até tem como usar, mas é complicado, acho que não vale a pena. Tentei mexer com isso uma vez, e não me aprofundei. Vou aguardar uma resposta de como fazer pra reaproveitar o visual entre as window =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, aqui vai uma explicação do meu ponto de vista sobre herança de visual e user Control Wpf.

**Como criar uma Herança visual wpf**

É bem simples e rápido fazer uma herança dentro do wpf, selecionar o item, escolher a propriedade a que receberá o valor herdado e definir o elemento pai(o que passa seu valor para os outros) como exibido nas imagens abaixo através de dois modelos, o *modelo 1* exibi o percudo através do modo gráfico e o *modelo 2* através do código:

[image: 1.1]

**1.1** Selecione o item a herdar os valores, escolha a propriedade(no caso background) e abra as opções da propriedade.

[image: 1.2]

**1.2** Escolha a opção *Criar Associação de dados*.

[image: 1.3]

**1.3** em *tipo de vinculação* selecione ElementName se o valor de herança está em um item da sua janela ou StaticResource se estiver em um recurso estático e então selecione o item na lista a esquerda e a propriedade a ser herdada na lista a direita.

**exemplo 2 - via código**

digamos que o item de herança(pai) será o *gridPrincipal* e o item herdeiro(filho) será o *gridMenu*, o código para associar o background(ou qualquer outra propriedade) do *gridMenu* o *gridPrincipal* seria:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridMenu" Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=gridPrincipal}"/>
```

**Existem vários outros processos que podem ser usados para associar dados entre janelas/usercontrols e etc, pesquise e use o mais adequado para sua necessidade**

Para mais detalhes sobre associação de dados wpf:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms750612(v=vs.110).aspx